# Defining key-bindings within `helm-map`: getting a `void-variable helm-map` error

Tags: key-bindings, helm

Am going through [this Helm tutorial](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html) at the moment; I pasted in the code verbatim (for now, I'll adapt it to suit my preferences later).

I did a quick google search for this particular error but it doesn't seem common.

For context, prior to adding the elisp code from the tutorial, I was indeed able to use the helm mini-buffer (i.e., helm is indeed installed correctly; i did it through MELPA).

Am including below the full error message that I see after running `emacs --debug-init` - please see top two lines.  (The initialization looks a bit funky in the lines further down because I have Emacs load from the `init.el` file in my Dropbox.)

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable helm-map)
  (define-key helm-map (kbd "C-i") (quote helm-execute-persistent-action))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-462666> nil "/home/dchaudh/Dropbox/dchaudhUbuntu/emacs/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3629
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/dchaudh/Dropbox/dchaudhUbuntu/emacs/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/dchaudh/Dropbox/dchaudhUbuntu/emacs/.emacs.d/init.el" nil nil)
  load("~/Dropbox/dchaudhUbuntu/emacs/.emacs.d/init.el")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/dchaudh/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 220
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/dchaudh/.emacs" "/home/dchaudh/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262 \306=\203\307\310Q\202; \311=\204\307\312Q\202;\313\307\314\315#\203*\316\202;\313\307\314\317#\203:\320\nB\321\202;\316\322\323\322\211#\210\322=\203a\324\325\326\307\327Q!\"\323\322\211#\210\322=\203`\210\203\243\330!\331\232\203\243\332!\211\333P\334!\203}\211\202\210\334!\203\207\202\210\314\262\203\241\335\"\203\237\336\337#\210\340\341!\210\266\f?\205\260\314\323\342\322\211#)\262\207" [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs" windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" (initialization "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'") "~/_emacs" t load expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7 "\n\n(fn)"]()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Comment: Could you paste the Helm code inside `~/.emacs.d/init.el` and just this file? And move your `~/.emacs` elsewhere. It seems like your `~/.emacs` is loading the other `init.el` inside your Dropbox directory. Your problem is that Helm is not yet loaded. Properly you run the Helm code prior to `(package-initialized)`? The same code is inside [module helm-everywhere in Emacs Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/blob/master/modules/prelude-helm-everywhere.el), and it works fine.

Comment: The code is split into two in Emacs Prelude; aside from helm-everywhere module, you also have [prelude-helm](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/blob/master/modules/prelude-helm.el). Would it be fine if you show your configuration?

Comment: You're right, it was because I hadn't initialized the package.  Happy to share my new Helm config...it's a copy paste of the helm setup from this emacs file: http://p.writequit.org/org/settings.html.  (Yes, I have it set up such that `~/.emacs` loads the `init.el` in my dropbox - it's intentional.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to configure Helm before it has been loaded.

If your init file contains code which depends on packages being available, then you need to call `(package-initialize)` beforehand.

See [Emacs 24 Package System Initialization Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11127109/324105) for details.

Comment: If `(package-initialize)` does not work, try `(require 'helm)` instead. That is what worked for me at least.

Comment: Yes, you have to put `(package-initialize)` and then load `helm`. Otherwise, Helm won't be available. If you do not put `(package-initialize)` first before `(require 'helm)`, then the error like the OP will occur. It seems like you are new to Helm; [my guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Here solution:

```
(eval-after-load "shell"
  '(define-key shell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-l") 'helm-comint-input-ring))
```

Comment: The idea might be right, but the question has nothing to do with `shell-mode-map`, so please edit your answer to actually fix the OP's problem.  It's also good to additionally explain *why* it's a solution.