# Defining key-bindings within `helm-map`: getting a `void-variable helm-map` error [continuation]

Tags: key-bindings, helm

Following the same steps as Dipak C in his question regarding [void-variable helm-map error](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/defining-key-bindings-within-helm-map-getting-a-void-variable-helm-map-erro) but still cannot solve the problem even after adding `(package-initialize)` just after `(require 'helm-config)` as I understand from the solution.

Comment: This question would probably make more sense as a comment on the answer to the original question asking for clarification, rather than as a separate question.  Please consider switching this to the comment option.

Comment: @Dan: I tried to add a comment on the answer to the original question but was not able to due to low reputation score. At the moment I have only 1 reputation score. AFAIK, commenting is allowed starting from 15 reputation points. This is why I created a kind of follow-up question.

Comment: "... cannot solve the problem even after adding `(package-initialize)` just after `(require 'helm-config)` as I understand from the solution." That is not what the solution says. You need to call `package-initialize` **before** making any customizations to third-party packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `package-initialize` after loading helm won't make a difference, doing it *before* loading helm *might*. Also see https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm#install-from-emacs-packaging-system and https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki#faq.