# Symbol's value as variable is void: company-backends

Tags: init-file, company-mode, ruby-mode

I'm trying to setup [robe](https://github.com/dgutov/robe) for Rails development. It needs [company mode](http://company-mode.github.io/)
and I have some issues with it:
Have following in `init.el`:

```
;; robe, documentation lookup and completion for Ruby
(require 'robe)
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'robe-mode)
(add-to-list 'load-path "./elpa/company-20150306.1548/")
(autoload 'company-mode "company" nil t)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(push 'company-robe company-backends)
;; end robe setup
```

It raises:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: company-backends
```

Full error trace is:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable company-backends)
  (cons (quote company-robe) company-backends)
  (setq company-backends (cons (quote company-robe) company-backends))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/me/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3073
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/me/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/me/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/me/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262 \306=\203\307\310Q\202; \311=\204\307\312Q\202;\313\307\314\315#\203*\316\202;\313\307\314\317#\203:\320\nB\321\202;\316\322\323\322\211#\210\322=\203a\324\325\326\307\327Q!\"\323\322\211#\210\322=\203`\210\203\243\330!\331\232\203\243\332!\211\333P\334!\203}\211\202\210\334!\203\207\202\210\314\262\203\241\335\"\203\237\336\337#\210\340\341!\210\266\f?\205\260\314\323\342\322\211#)\262\207" [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs" windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" (initialization "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'") "~/_emacs" t load expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7 "\n\n(fn)"]()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

I'm newbie in Emacs world and I can't figure out why `company-backends` is void?
I doubt that somewhere it is not set and I should set it to myself but I can't find the way to do this.

### Edit

- Emacs version is `GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.7) of 2014-03-07 on lamiak, modified by Debian` on `Ubuntu 14.04.1`

Comment: If you `(require 'company)` does the error go away?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining key-bindings within \`helm-map\`: getting a \`void-variable helm-map\` error](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/defining-key-bindings-within-helm-map-getting-a-void-variable-helm-map-erro)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You've configured company-mode to load after your init file is evaluated using the `after-init-hook`, but are then trying to modify `company-backends` right away.

That variable isn't defined until company-mode is loaded. You either need to just `require` company, or defer setting that variable using `eval-after-load`:

```
(eval-after-load 'company
    '(push 'company-robe company-backends)))
```

Another option would be to modify the company backends in a mode hook for robe or ruby. That approach would allow you to set different company backends for different modes. For example, this will use only the robe backend in ruby mode:

```
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
        (lambda ()
          (setq-local company-backends '((company-robe)))))
```

Comment: In Emacs 24.4 and later it is preferred to use `with-eval-after-load` instead of `eval-after-load`

Comment: @glucas Second option is just what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @Håkon Hægland I have it in mind for the future but this is Emacs 24.3.1 (question is updated)