# Symbol's value as variable is void: company-transformers

Tags: init-file, company-mode, use-package

I am trying to prevent company-mode from autocompleting numbers. I added the following to my init file.

```
  (push (apply-partially #'cl-remove-if
               (lambda (c) (string-match-p "\\`[0-9]+\\'" c)))
      company-transformers)
```

I am now getting this message

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: company-transformers
```

This is the relevant part of my init file for company-mode

```
  (use-package company
    :bind (:map company-active-map
    ("C-n" . company-select-next)
    ("C-p" . company-select-previous)
    ("M-h" . company-show-doc-buffer))
    :custom
    (company-idle-delay 0)
    (company-selection-wrap-around t)
    (company-tooltip-limit 10)
    (company-minimum-prefix-length 1)
    :hook
     (after-init . global-company-mode))


  (push (apply-partially #'cl-remove-if
               (lambda (c) (string-match-p "\\`[0-9]+\\'" c)))
      company-transformers)
```

I found this on StackExchange, [Symbol's value as variable is void: company-backends](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9890/symbols-value-as-variable-is-void-company-backends), but I can't figure out how to adapt it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `:config` section to the `use-package` declaration and move the code that modifies `company-transformers` to that section:

```el
 (use-package company
    :bind (:map company-active-map
    ("C-n" . company-select-next)
    ("C-p" . company-select-previous)
    ("M-h" . company-show-doc-buffer))
    :custom
    (company-idle-delay 0)
    (company-selection-wrap-around t)
    (company-tooltip-limit 10)
    (company-minimum-prefix-length 1)
    :config
    (push (apply-partially #'cl-remove-if
                           (lambda (c) (string-match-p "\\`[0-9]+\\'" c)))
          company-transformers)
    :hook
     (after-init . global-company-mode))
```

The doc string for `use-package` says:

```
For full documentation, please see the README file that came with
this file.  Usage:

  (use-package package-name
     [:keyword [option]]...)

:init            Code to run before PACKAGE-NAME has been loaded.
:config          Code to run after PACKAGE-NAME has been loaded.  Note that
                 if loading is deferred for any reason, this code does not
                 execute until the lazy load has occurred.
...
```

`use-package` does not necessarily *load* the package and so `company-transformers` is not necessarily defined after the `use-package` declaration. A similar problem occurs e.g. if in your init file, you try to modify `company-transformers` before the package is loaded (with `require` or `load-library`): the name is not defined and when emacs tries to evaluate it (as it will, when you are trying to `push` to it: it has to know the old value at that point), it fails with the `Symbol's value as variable is void` error message. Invariably, this message means that you are trying to evaluate a variable before it is defined.