# void-variable dired-after-readin-hook in emacs 25

Tags: init-file, dired, start-up

I've get emacs 25 build ppa taken from this [ask ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851633/emacs-25-on-ubuntu-16-10)

and I have this functions and macro:

```
(defun remove-lambda-helper (list matcher)
  "function that remove lambda from a list if match the function `matcher'"
  (dolist (item list list)
    (if (and (listp item) (eq (car item) 'lambda))
        (when (funcall matcher item)
          (setq list (delete item list))))))


(defun remove-project-specifics-lambda (name hook)
  "Remove lambda from a hook that have code from `project-specifics'"
  (set hook
       (remove-lambda-helper (symbol-value hook)
                             (lambda (body)
                               (equal (cadr (cadr (caddr body))) name)))))

(defmacro project-specifics (name &rest body)
  (declare (indent 1))
  (let ((item (gensym)))
    `(progn
       (remove-project-specifics-lambda ,name 'find-file-hook)
       (remove-project-specifics-lambda ,name 'dired-after-readin-hook)
       (add-hook 'find-file-hook (lambda ()
                                   (when (string-match-p ,name (buffer-file-name))
                                     ,@body)))
       (add-hook 'dired-after-readin-hook
                 (lambda ()
                   (when (string-match-p ,name (dired-current-directory))
                     ,@body))))))
```

and I got error (the macro works fine in 24.5.1):

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable dired-after-readin-hook)
```

if I try <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> dired-after-readin-hook, I got `[no match]`

was that hook removed or replaced with different one? I know that I can use directory specific file, but I want my macro to work, anybody know why this return error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining key-bindings within \`helm-map\`: getting a \`void-variable helm-map\` error](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/defining-key-bindings-within-helm-map-getting-a-void-variable-helm-map-erro)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that dired is not enabled by default, I've needed to add:

```
(require 'dired)
```

Comment: `emacs -Q --batch --eval "(message \"%S\" (featurep 'dired))"` prints `nil` for me using Emacs 24.5 as well, maybe it's a change in the Ubuntu package.

Comment: @npastavs I also have nil on 24.5, the problem was `w3m` package that seems to require dired for me.

Comment: Ah, well, you might want to look at `boundp` and/or `bound-and-true-p` instead of loading `dired` eagerly.